# How to write unit tests for a protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, core-data, xctest

The protocol is used by a custom view controller.
I am not sure if this is the correct way to go, but right now I am  instantiating the view controller inside the unit test class.

Currently I am trying to do this:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Transactions") as! TransactionsViewController
}
```

But it says `Use of undeclared type 'TransactionsViewController'`.

Is this the way to go ? If yes, how do I make the view controller visible ?

Comment: Did you import the module with `TransactionsViewController`?

Comment: Yes, its imported, I can access other classes, but not the view controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests are usually a separate target, so to make files from your main target visible to the test targets you have to change their **Target membership** in the `File Inspector`.

[image]

In your case your should share both `Main.storyboard` and `TransactionsViewController` to your test target.

Comment: Thanks, adding both the view controller file and storyboard did the trick.

Comment: No, you should never need to add production code to a test target.

Comment: Otherwise, how would you write tests on a production code if it's not available?

Comment: For iOS tests, the app is launched on simulator. The test target is injected into the running app. Through that, and `@testable import`, it should have access to the production code. When it doesn't, something is wrong: that is, something is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 2, you can import the module you're trying to write tests for with:

```
@testable import ModuleName
```

With this method, you do not need to manually add files from your App Target to your Test Target.

So, if your main target is named "MyApp" and your test target is "MyAppTests", you can just include this at the top of each test file you're writing:

```
@testable import MyApp
```

Comment: It's already imported. I can use other classes from it, not the view controllers. Do they have to be public ?

Comment: @Kobe: They shouldn't have to be `public` only `internal` which is the default access scope and what `@testable import` lets you have access to from the test target. I can reference ViewController classes just fine from my test targets. Manually adding the files to the test target will definitely work, but it shouldn't be required and can get complicated if you start adding lots of files. Can you post the declaration for your TransactionsViewController?